# Force method attributes to be as given values

Tags: php, methods, attributes

I have method in class:

```
class SomeClass{

   public function someMethod($status){
        echo $status;
   }

}
```

I know what `$status` can be **1** or **0**.

Is it possible to force method work only with that values? So for code:

```
$class = new SomeClass();
$class->someMethod(2);
```

get some error (fatal, warning, notice).

P.S. `if($status != 1 && $status != 2)` is not good solution for me.

Comment: If you values only can be 0 or 1 use boolean(TRUE or FALSE). But if you need integers I think you should check via "if clause" and throw exception for any other value.

Comment: if(is_bool($status))
because you are sure that values are 1 or 0 and if it's not return your own error

Comment: No, **0** and **1** is for example, it can be anything, even not number.

Answer (score 0):

U can use [assert](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.assert.php) function, but **if** statement is better